# How to create a textbox that display message when mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sql query that obtain a string **called description** from the database

Also , i have a table that contain a mail list

I would like **for each mail list name, when the mouse over it, it display a text block that contain the description**

Are there any plugin , or how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: You don't need a plugin, the ability to display a message when moused over is built in to textboxes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a jQuery plug-in called [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin), which is very simple to implement.

Comment: It is easy to use and good suggestion, but i found it can not display the text after a space? Is it the bug? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP(for the query). You can use whatever, this is an example.

```
<?php
  $q = 'your sql query'
  $query = mysql_query($query)
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
  <div class="email-list-name-<?=$row['id']?>"> <?=$row['email-list-name']?> </div>
  <div class='description-for-email' style='display:none;'><?=$row['description']?></div>  
<?php  } ?>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('div[id^="email-list-name"]').click(function(){
    $('.description-for-email').hide(); //hide all message displays
    $(this).next('.description-for-email').show();  //show the next description for our email we clicked
  });
});
```

You didn't really provide any other information, so I just threw together a general example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the title attribute of html for that or make use of tooltip .  You can easily find an example of tooltip.  But if you trying to fetch the data from your db on the run time..i would say thats a bad idea